# Pandas Dynamic Row-Based Equity Calculation

Tags: python, pandas

I've been beating my head against a wall trying to figure out the best approach on this question. I have a SLOW backtester in Excel that I'm trying to port to pandas. I thought I'd be able to leverage the power of python rather than merely recreate the Excel functions in python, but I'm stuck!

The key challenge is in portfolio P&L calculation for multiple and dynamically changing instruments over time. For example, based on criteria, I want to buy instrument A and C for the first N periods. Then I want to use B and C for the next N periods. And so on. I want to buy  proportional amounts of each instrument based on current equity (as opposed to buying 100 shares each time or something).

The Excel, row-based function calculates shares first based on initial equity, but then based on equity available "in the previous row". Something like: *IF(RebalancePeriod = TRUE, EquityFromPrevRow / CurrentSharePrice, PreviousRowShares)*

Attempting panda-ize it. Here are example **inputs:**

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
from pandas import *

dates = date_range('1/1/2000', periods=6)
index=dates
data = {'A': pd.Series([20, 30, 10, 0, 0, 0], index=index)
    , 'B': pd.Series([0, 0, 0, 50, 51, 52], index=index)
    , 'C': pd.Series([11, 12, 20, 18, 17, 19], index=index)}

initial_capital = 5000.0

prices = pd.DataFrame(data, index=dates)
```

That doesn't get you very far, but here are the **desired outputs**. In this example, I want to rebalance instruments by swapping from A to B at the 4th row, 2000-01-04, where A=0 thereafter.

```
Prices          
            A   B   C
2000-01-01  20  0   11
2000-01-02  30  0   12
2000-01-03  10  0   20
2000-01-04  0   50  18
2000-01-05  0   51  17
2000-01-06  0   52  19

Shares (initial or current equity / price)          
            A       B       C
2000-01-01  250.0   0.0     454.5
2000-01-02  250.0   0.0     454.5
2000-01-03  250.0   0.0     454.5
2000-01-04  0.0     115.9   322.0
2000-01-05  0.0     115.9   322.0
2000-01-06  0.0     115.9   322.0


Equity (shares * price)             
            A       B       C       Total
2000-01-01  5,000.0 0.0     5,000.0 10,000.0
2000-01-02  7,500.0 0.0     5,454.5 12,954.5
2000-01-03  2,500.0 0.0     9,090.9 11,590.9
2000-01-04  0.0     5,795.5 5,795.5 11,590.9
2000-01-05  0.0     5,911.4 5,473.5 11,384.8
2000-01-06  0.0     6,027.3 6,117.4 12,144.7
```

I realize there's a lot in this one. I appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just follow the same idea that you do in the `Excel`, the only difference is that the `excel function` applied to each row is now expressed as a loop:

```
In [113]:

print prices
             A   B   C
2000-01-01  20   0  11
2000-01-02  30   0  12
2000-01-03  10   0  20
2000-01-04   0  50  18
2000-01-05   0  51  17
2000-01-06   0  52  19
In [114]:
swap=pd.Series([False,]*len(dates),index=dates, name='sawp')
swap[3]=True
total=pd.DataFrame({'A':0, 'B':0, 'C':0},index=dates)
total.ix[0]=[5000,5000,5000]
shares=total/prices
shares['swap']=swap
In [115]:
#the loop
for idx in range(1, len(shares)):
    if shares.ix[idx, 'swap']:
        shares.ix[idx, ['A','B','C']]=(shares.ix[idx-1, ['A','B','C']]*prices.ix[idx-1]).sum()/2/prices.ix[idx]
    else:
        shares.ix[idx, ['A','B','C']]=shares.ix[idx-1, ['A','B','C']]
In [116]:
#Get rid of the infinite numbers
shares[shares==np.inf]=0
In [117]:

print shares
              A           B           C   swap
2000-01-01  250    0.000000  454.545455  False
2000-01-02  250    0.000000  454.545455  False
2000-01-03  250    0.000000  454.545455  False
2000-01-04    0  115.909091  321.969697   True
2000-01-05    0  115.909091  321.969697  False
2000-01-06    0  115.909091  321.969697  False
In [118]:

print shares*prices
               A            B            C  swap
2000-01-01  5000     0.000000  5000.000000   NaN
2000-01-02  7500     0.000000  5454.545455   NaN
2000-01-03  2500     0.000000  9090.909091   NaN
2000-01-04     0  5795.454545  5795.454545   NaN
2000-01-05     0  5911.363636  5473.484848   NaN
2000-01-06     0  6027.272727  6117.424242   NaN
In [119]:
#Total asserts
print (shares*prices).sum(1)
2000-01-01    10000.000000
2000-01-02    12954.545455
2000-01-03    11590.909091
2000-01-04    11590.909091
2000-01-05    11384.848485
2000-01-06    12144.696970
Freq: D, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks! Seems like this is what I need. Unfortunately, something's not working with the loop. I get `KeyError: 'swap'` pointing to the `if` statement. I thought it was a datatype issue (i.e. float vs bool), but tweaking that didn't resolve the error.

Comment: Sorry, `shares=total/prices` is missing from `[in] 114`, edited. That should be the issue.

Comment: Yes. Helpful. It seems that the `if` condition always evals to `True`. Ack. Premature post. Outputs now:
`                         A           B           C  swap
    2000-01-01  250.000000    0.000000  454.545455   NaN
    2000-01-02  166.666667    0.000000  416.666667   NaN
    2000-01-03  500.000000    0.000000  250.000000   NaN
    2000-01-04    0.000000  100.000000  277.777778   NaN
    2000-01-05    0.000000   98.039216  294.117647   NaN
    2000-01-06    0.000000   96.153846  263.157895   NaN`
I wonder if swap datatype is a problem? I tried this: `swap = pd.Series(False, index=dates)`.

Comment: Yikes. That didn't post well. Is there a way display the outputs better?

Comment: Turns out the way the `swap` series was made resulting in a wrong series in `pandas 0.14.0`, changed that everything works. Again see `[in] 114`. `swap=pd.Series({'swap':False},index=dates)` results in a series of `nan`s in `float dtype`, not the intended `bool` type `False`.

Comment: Got it. All good! Seems so obvious...AFTER I see how it's supposed to be done. Thanks for the answer and working through details!